# Reactjs i want to get the minumum price from this array list how can i get it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

in reactjs im trying to this suppose my array list is something like this i want to get the minmum price from this list...suppose the 'totalll': 100 how can i do that please let me know. array->object->array->totalll

```
const data = [
  {
    name: "test",
    lab_partners: [
      {
        id: 0,
        totalll: 5000,
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        totalll: 200,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        totalll: 1000,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "test",
    lab_partners: [
      {
        id: 0,
        totalll: 7000,
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        totalll: 100,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        totalll: 800,
      },
    ],
  },
];

const minTotalByName = (data, id) => {
  const totals = data.filter((x) => x.lab_partners.find((y) => y.id === id));

  return Math.min(...totals);
};

const min = minTotalByName(data);
console.log(min, "min");
```

Comment: It's unlikely that that's your actual data, since JavaScript objects can't have two values with the same key. You now have an object with two `lab_partners` values.

Comment: sorry..i have updated the array please check it agian @AKX

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const totals = data
  .map((d) => d.lab_partners)
  .flat()
  .map((p) => p.totalll);
const minTotal = Math.min(...totals);
```

and you'll end up with `100` in `minTotal`.

If you need the full object with the lowest `totalll`, things get a little more complicated, but we can (for once with good conscience) use `.reduce`:

```
const lowestPartner = data
  .map((d) => d.lab_partners)
  .flat()
  .reduce(
    (currentMin, obj) =>
      !currentMin || obj.totalll < currentMin.totalll ? obj : currentMin,
    null,
  );
// {id: 1, totalll: 100}
```

Comment: Or, `const minTotal = Math.min(...(data.map(d => d.lab_partners).flat().map(p => p.totalll)));` - to get just the minimum value.

Comment: @jsN00b Yes, you can of course combine the two statements.